# DukTape `require()` throws `TypeError: undefined not callable`

Tags: javascript, android, duktape

I am trying to use `Duktape` for Android and JavaScript bindings.

I followed the documentation here https://wiki.duktape.org/HowtoModules.html and as per the steps, I have the following calling code:

```
DuktapeContext::DuktapeContext(JavaVM* javaVM)
    : m_context(duk_create_heap(nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, &m_context, fatalErrorHandler))
    , m_objectType(m_javaValues.getObjectType(getEnvFromJavaVM(javaVM))) {
  if (!m_context) {
    throw std::bad_alloc();
  }
  duk_module_duktape_init(m_context); //<~~~ adds support for `require()`
  // Stash the JVM object in the context, so we can find our way back from a Duktape C callback.
  duk_push_global_stash(m_context);
  duk_push_pointer(m_context, javaVM);
  duk_put_prop_string(m_context, -2, JAVA_VM_PROP_NAME);
  duk_pop(m_context);
}
```

`duk_module_duktape_init` is defined like this (out-of-the-box, I did not edit this):

```
/* Register `require` as a global function. */
duk_eval_string(ctx,
                "(function(req){"
                "var D=Object.defineProperty;"
                "D(req,'name',{value:'require'});"
                "D(this,'require',{value:req,writable:true,configurable:true});"
                "D(Duktape,'modLoaded',{value:Object.create(null),writable:true,configurable:true});"
                "})");
duk_push_c_function(ctx, duk__require, 1 /*nargs*/);
```

In my `javascript` file `sample.js` I have the following line:

`var mod = require('tester');`

which, when the script is evaluated through Duktape, throws an exception`Caused by: com.squareup.duktape.DuktapeException: TypeError: undefined not callable at JavaScript.eval`(line where the `require()` is called)

Do I have to implement `Duktape.modSearch()` function also ? I thought I can get away by simply using `require()` ?

Answer (score 1):

Since module resolving and loading depends on the platform you are required to implement that yourself. The module handling that comes with duktape only deals with managing the loaded modules and provides the `require` call (you don't need to provide this function yourself). Registering the 2 functions is simple ([see also the entire code](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-workbench/blob/8.0/tools/mga/src/library/scripting-context.cpp#L109)):

```
// Module loading support.
duk_push_object(_ctx);
duk_push_c_function(_ctx, resolveModule, JSExport::VarArgs);
duk_put_prop_string(_ctx, -2, "resolve");
duk_push_c_function(_ctx, loadModule, JSExport::VarArgs);
duk_put_prop_string(_ctx, -2, "load");
duk_module_node_init(_ctx, normalizeFilename);
```

The actual resolution and loading code is a bit more involved. You can see the full code [in the scripting context class](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-workbench/blob/8.0/tools/mga/src/library/scripting-context.cpp#L1521).

Comment: I'm a complete beginner when it comes to javaScript. Anything except plain JS is confusing for me. I have 1 single `js` file. Inside this file, I have several `objects` and `functions` and `properties`. However, whatever I try to do with `duktape`, I get: `global object not found` or `object XXX does not have method called YYY`. Everything inside the `js` script is defined with `module` and `module.exports`. The developer that wrote the script told me it's built using `commonJS` - but this does not tell me much. Do I still need extra `module` loading if I have everything in one asset?

Comment: @Mike I face the same issue when I build my app with Proguard. WIthout Proguard being enabled, the app runs just fine.